# two image refresh java script not running together

Tags: javascript, image, refresh

i am trying to run two image refresh javascripts on the same page but one of them does not run, what am i doing wrong? I am using this for two different webcam images. Is it not enough to duplicate the script?

```
  <a href="webcam/Webcam.jpg" ><img name="refresh" src="webcam/" alt="Vefmyndavél-1 Miðhúsa     loading..." width="980" height="540"   > </a>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
  <!--
  var t = 5 // interval in seconds
  image = "webcam/Webcam.jpg" //name of the image
  function Start() {
  tmp = new Date();
  tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
  document.images["refresh"].src = image+tmp
  setTimeout("Start()", t*1000)
  }
  Start();
  // -->
  </SCRIPT>





 <a href="webcam2/Webcam2.jpg" ><img name="refresh1" src="webcam2/" alt="Vefmyndavél-2 Miðhúsa loading..." width="980" height="540"  > </a>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
  <!--
  var t = 5 // interval in seconds
  image = "webcam2/Webcam2.jpg" //name of the image
  function Start() {
  tmp = new Date();
  tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
  document.images["refresh1"].src = image+tmp
  setTimeout("Start()", t*1000)
  }
  Start();
  // -->
  </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the first function `Start()` with the second function `Start()` in your html document. Keep in mind that you have an global namespace in javascript.

One dirty and quick solution is to rename the second `function`!

For example:

```
    <a href="webcam/Webcam.jpg" ><img name="refresh" src="webcam/" alt="Vefmyndavél-1 Miðhúsa     loading..." width="980" height="540"   > </a>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
  <!--
  var t = 5 // interval in seconds
  imageOne = "webcam/Webcam.jpg" //name of the image
  function Start() {
  tmp = new Date();
  tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
  document.images["refresh"].src = imageOne+tmp
  setTimeout("StartFirst()", t*1000)
  }
  Start();
  // -->
  </SCRIPT>





 <a href="webcam2/Webcam2.jpg" ><img name="refresh1" src="webcam2/" alt="Vefmyndavél-2 Miðhúsa loading..." width="980" height="540"  > </a>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
  <!--
  var t = 5 // interval in seconds
  imageTwo = "webcam2/Webcam2.jpg" //name of the image
  function StartSecond() {
  tmp = new Date();
  tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
  document.images["refresh1"].src = imageTwo+tmp
  setTimeout("StartSecond()", t*1000)
  }
  StartSecond();
  // -->
  </SCRIPT>
```

**UPDATE**

One way to simplify your script:

```
<a href="webcam/Webcam.jpg" ><img name="refresh" src="webcam/" alt="Vefmyndavél-1 Miðhúsa     loading..." width="980" height="540"   > </a>
<a href="webcam2/Webcam2.jpg" ><img name="refresh1" src="webcam2/" alt="Vefmyndavél-2 Miðhúsa loading..." width="980" height="540"  > </a>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
  // Fires after page is loaded
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {

     // Called every 5 seconds updateImages();
     setTimeout("updateImages()", 5000);

     //Helper function to change src attribute of image tag
     function updateImages(){
        tmp = "?" + new Date().getTime();
        document.images["refresh"].src = "webcam/Webcam.jpg" + tmp;
        document.images["refresh1"].src = "webcam/Webcam2.jpg" + tmp;
     }
  });
  </SCRIPT>
```

The script below register an `load` event on the `window` object. The code within will be executed after page load and start an timer task to update the images.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer...but this seems not to work. It now loads both images first right...then shows the same image on both... and only loads one image after that. How could i simplfy this to one script? I just need a script to refresh two images from two differnt webcams on my page.

Comment: I have updated my snippet. Sorry I have overlooked the variabel `image`. Same problem with the namespace. For example you could add an parameter to your `function` to control which image should be updated. But I think there are more problems... What If an image isn't available on server? It is correct that the path to your image is `webcam2/Webcam2.jpg1413217641949 ` ?

Comment: the path is webcam2/Webcam2.jpg

i used your updated code and
at the moment just webcam.jpg is auto refreshing
not webcam2.jpg

i am a total beginner in this, before i just had one image with auto refresh that did run well....but adding a second one is a headache

Comment: Sorry my mistake... I have forgotten to update the first function parameter from `setTimeout`. So it make sense that only your first image will be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks a million! Everthing works flawlessly and also thanks for the simplified version.

Comment: NP! - Can you mark the question as resolved, please?